# declared property being initialized multiple times when using data binding

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer, web-component

**Polymer v1.2.3**

---

I am running into an issue with Polymer and I'm not sure if its a bug or not.

I have this property that I need to set to null after doing something with it in the `ready` call back, however it seems like when I am initializing the property via data binding, the property gets re-initialized  after I set it to null.

Take the following example:

**proxy-elm.html**

```
<dom-module id="proxy-elm">
  <template>
    <x-foo it="[[prox]]"></x-foo>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'proxy-elm',
      properties: {
        prox: String
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**x-foo.html**

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <div>...</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-foo',
      properties: {
        it: String
      },
      ready: function () {
        //some processing stuff
        console.log(this.it);
        this.it = '';
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log("later -- " + this.it);
        }.bind(this), 3000);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**Main.html**

```
<proxy-elm prox="hi"></proxy-elm>
```

**Console**

```
=>hi
=>
=>later -- hi
```

This issue only occurs then the proxy element uses data binding. If I have the proxy element set `it` to an immediate, the console looks like:

```
=>hi
=>
=> later --
```

Which is the desired behavior.

---

What's up with this? I'm going mad!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the initialization order (cf. [Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#initialization-order))

You can try in the `ready()` function from your proxy to set the value of `x-foo` as desired like this:

```
<dom-module id="proxy-elm">
  <template>
    <x-foo id="xFoo" it="[[prox]]"></x-foo>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'proxy-elm',
      properties: {
        prox: String
      },
      ready: function () {
        this.$.xFoo.it = '';
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

and keep the `ready()` function of `x-foo` for your specific processing!

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed confusing. However, when reading the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#ready-method) very carefully, I noticed that it only mentions **local dom**.

> It is called after the element’s template has been stamped and all elements **inside the element’s local DOM** have been configured (with values bound from parents, deserialized attributes, or else default values) and had their ready method called.

So the local children of your element are guaranteed to have been initialized, but not necessarily the attributes of your element.
I noticed that wrapping the code in an `async` helps.

```
  ready: function () {
    //some processing stuff
    console.log(this.it);
    this.async(function(){
      this.it = '';
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("later -- " + this.it);
    }.bind(this), 3000);
  }
```

Comment: I'm wondering why it would be available at all in ready though. Clearly it gets set before ready, but then it gets set *again*

Comment: Yes, I also found that confusing. Maybe you can ask that on Github and see if any of the developers can give a reason or an explain the current behaviour.